# compare 2 arrays and remove similar values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, comparison

I have 2 arrays

First one is like this

```
$sql1 = "SELECT userid FROM interest where interest='".$interest."' and userid!='".$myuserid."'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
        {
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
                {
                    $userid = $row1["userid"];
                    $user[] = array($userid);                       
                }
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r ($user);
            echo "</pre>";  
        }
```

It's o/p is like this

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 8
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 9
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )   

    )
```

The second one is like this

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM block where blockedby='".$myuserid."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                    $blockeduser=$row["blockeduser"];
                    $block[] = array($blockeduser,$myuserid);
                }  

                echo "<pre>";
                    print_r ($block);
                echo "</pre>";

        }
```

It's o/p is like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )

    )
```

I wish to compare these two arrays and remove the similar values in the resulting array.. the array that i should get as final result should be like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 8
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 9
            )

    )
```

I tried

```
 $unique=array_unique( array_merge($block, $user) );
    $block=array_diff($unique, $block);
    print_r($block);
```

but i got this as result

```
 Array
    (
    )
```

Can anyone please tell how i can achieve this result

Comment: print_r ($unique) ... what is output?

Answer (score 0):

Array_unique can't work with multidimentional arrays.Let's make it's functionality by array_filter

```
$values = array();

$new = array_filter(array_merge($block, $user), 
          function($i) use(&$values) { 
             if( !in_array($i[0], $values)) 
                { $values[] =  $i[0]; return true;} 
             return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since array_unique don't work with multidimentional arrays .

May be there's better way... but this works for me to remove similar values from multidimentional ...

```
$array1 = array(
 array("a" => "green"),
 array("b" => "brown"), 
 array("c" => "blue")
);
$array2 = array(
 array("a" => "red"),
 array("b" => "yellow"), 
 array("c" => "blue")
 );
```

Firstly merge arrays with **array_merge_recursive** since these are multidimentional array

```
$array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Then recursively get all values from arrays

```
$values="";
```

function get_values($inarray){
      global $values;

```
  foreach ($inarray as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            get_values($value);
        }else{
          $values.=",".$value;
            echo $key."=>".$value."<br/>";
        }

  }
 return $values;
}



$values=get_values($array);
```

// return values 
//,green,brown,blue,red,yellow,blue

```
 $values=ltrim($values,",");
```

//After ltrim return values
//green,brown,blue,red,yellow,blue

```
 $valuesArr=explode(",",$values);
```

Here with explode get all values as a onedimensional array
Now we can use array_unique function to get rid of similar values between arrays.

```
$uniqueValue=array_unique($valuesArr);
print_r($uniqueValue);
```

With out repetition of any values result

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => green
    [1] => brown
    [2] => blue
    [3] => red
    [4] => yellow
  )